# What variety of euphorbia is this?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents

This Euphorbia has been in the garden for quite some time. It's labeled as heterochroma, but I'm not so sure about that.

[image: E.Heterochroma]

[Branch http://selva.cabal.mx/Pic4.jpg](http://selva.cabal.mx/Pic4.jpg)

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I see you've [found the answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30056/what-variety-of-euphorbia-is-this#comment38707_30067), good Job! This is [*Euphorbia heterochroma* subsp. *heterochroma*](http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/record/kew-80083). See comparison picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, this wasn't fair.  The dang label was right there!  Euphorbia heterochroma. Grins, is there a reason you didn't believe the label?  Are you growing this plant?

Comment: This is my plant and the label is mine, but photos of heterochroma look different than mine. Thus I am seeking either a new name of confirmation of the label heterochroma

Comment: . I have just learned that there re several sub species of e. heterochroma which look very different from each other. Mine is . e. heterochroma ssp heterochroma

Comment: Whoa.  This sounds completely sensible...good job Richard!

Comment: Went out to go look at pictures (sigh) of your Euphorbia and heterochroma also means differences within an individual. Such as two different colored eyes.  There are so many different looking plants in this Genus I can now see why they named it heterochroma.https://www.google.com/search?q=heterochroma+ssp+heterochroma&rlz=1C1QJDB_en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg1trwodvQAhUFX5QKHTPGBvsQ7AkILw&biw=1280&bih=646